# apache2 The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/autoindex.conf at line 21 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, alias

As delivered on 22.04, in the apache2 package, there is a duplicate alias definitions for /usr/share/httpd/icons. The alias of /icons/ is found in both mods-available/alias.conf and conf-available/autoindex.conf.

This results in a message AH00558 any time apachectl does a start, restart, etc.

```
[Fri Jul 21 16:53:27.068494 2023] [alias:warn] [pid 30296:tid 140675997558656] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/autoindex.conf at line 21 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
```

I realize that I could remove one of them, but is there a reason for both, and why this is left as an exercise for the sysadmin?